# Transpose a row into columns with MySQL without using UNIONS?

Tags: sql, mysql, transpose

I have a table that is similar to the following below:

```
       id |        cat |         one_above |        top_level | 
        0    'printers'          'hardware'        'computers'
```

I want to be able to write a query, **without using unions**, that will return me a result set that transposes this table's columns into rows. What this means, is that I want the result to be:

```
       id |          cat |
        0      'printers'
        0      'hardware'
        0     'computers'
```

Is this possible in MySQL? I can not drop down to the application layer and perform this because I'm feeding these into a search engine that will index based on the id. Various other DBMS have something like PIVOT and UNPIVOT. I would appreciate any insight to something that I'm missing.

Mahmoud

P.S.

I'm considering re-normalization of the database as a last option, since this won't be a trivial task.

Thanks!

Comment: not possible in current MySql

Comment: PIVOT/UNPIVOT has been supported in SQL Server 2005+, and Oracle 11g+.  I'm not aware of any other db supporting the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this out of the book [The Art of SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008945), pages 284-286:

Let's say your table name is `foo`.

First, create a table called `pivot`:

```
CREATE Table pivot (
  count int
);
```

Insert into that tables as many rows as there are columns that you want to pivot in `foo`. Since you have three columns in `foo` that you want to pivot, create three rows in the pivot table:

```
insert into pivot values (1);
insert into pivot values (2);
insert into pivot values (3);
```

Now do a Cartesian join between `foo` and `pivot`, using a `CASE` to select the correct column based on the count:

```
SELECT foo.id, Case pivot.count
  When 1 Then cat
  When 2 Then one_above
  When 3 Then top_level
End Case
FROM foo JOIN pivot;
```

This should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Barry, I'm going to try something like this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

After some fairly extensive digging I stumbled on [this page](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1108#78) which may or may not contain your answer. It's a difficult in MySQL but from a conceptual point of view I can construct a query that would transpose like this using describe (though it would probably perform horribly). So I'm sure that we can figure out a way to do it the right way.