# Select rows and display as columns from mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

All,
I've got the following mySQL table structure:

```
Table dj_feedback_answers: answer_id, gig_id, question_id, answer_id
Table dj_feedback_summary: summary_id, user_id, gig_date, tip, summary, why_poor, why_fair
Table dj_feedback_questions: question_id, question_value, question_display
Table dj_feedback_ratings: rating_id, rating_value, rating_display
```

I'm basically asking users questions and the questions are stored in the dj_feedback_questions table and allowing them to give a rating for each question. The ratings are stored in the dj_feedback_ratings.

Each form can having variable questions so when I submit the questions I store the answers in the dj_feedback_answers. There are other more static fields on the form and those get svaed into the dj_feedback_summary. The summary_id and the gig_id are the keys that connect the two tables for the answers that the user submitted.

This means that there can be multiple rows in the dj_feedback_answers for a single row in the dj_feedback_summary table.

What I would like to do is basically be able to utilize the results in a PHP table. So I'd like my results to look something like this (assuming there are three questions in the dj_feedback_questions table):

```
summary_id, user_id, gig_date, tip, summary, why_poor, why_fair, question_1, question_2, question_3
1, 2, 07/23/2012, 5, This is a summary, It was poor, It was fair, 3, 4, 5
```

The values that would be stored for the questions would be the answer_id from the dj_feedback_answers.

I tried to create the following query to get my results. This works ok but it only can display a single question instead of all of the questions.

```
Select dj_feedback_summary.summary_id, 
       dj_feedback_summary.user_id, 
       dj_feedback_summary.gig_date, 
       dj_feedback_summary.tip, 
       dj_feedback_summary.summary,  
       dj_feedback_answers.question_id, 
       dj_feedback_answers.rating_id, 
       dj_feedback_questions.question_value, 
       users.first_name, users.last_name, 
       dj_feedback_ratings.rating_value
from dj_feedback_summary
join dj_feedback_answers on dj_feedback_summary.summary_id=dj_feedback_answers.gig_id
join dj_feedback_questions on dj_feedback_answers.question_id=dj_feedback_questions.question_id 
join users on dj_feedback_summary.user_id=users.user_id
join dj_feedback_ratings on dj_feedback_ratings.rating_id=dj_feedback_answers.rating_id
where dj_feedback_questions.question_value='Overall Gig'
order by dj_feedback_summary.summary_id DESC
```

Is there a way to modify my query so it can return my results how I would like them?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need values from multiple rows displayed, and it's not essential that they be in separate columns, then the MySQL [GROUP CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) would probably suit your purposes.

That would give you `question_1`, `question_2`, and `question_3` values concatenated into a single column (if I understand your output intent correctly).

**Update:** To do a more "genuine" pivot (separating the answers to different questions into different columns), you could use one of the following approaches:

**1) Use multiple table aliases:** join to the `dj_feedback_questions` table one time for each question, e.g. something along these lines:

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...]
LEFT JOIN dj_feedback_questions q1 on q1.question_id = 1
LEFT JOIN dj_feedback_questions q2 on q2.question_id = 2
LEFT JOIN dj_feedback_questions q3 on q2.question_id = 3
```

You will then need to a) join to `dj_feedback_answers` similarly (multiple times with aliases), since you get to it via `question_id`, and you want different questions separated into different columns, and b) aggregate the results and decide how you want to handle nulls, since doing a regular `JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` will cause you to lose the row for any summary that lacks an answer to one or more questions.

**2) Break into columns with an `IF` block:** See this SO question (specifically the accepted answer) for an illustration: [Transpose mysql query rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685601/transpose-mysql-query-rows-into-columns)

Comment: Thanks but my output intent is to have an output column for each row that was in my answers table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. If I don't know how many questions there are (since it's variable) is there a way to just make the query say left join for that variable number of questions?