# columns to row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I need help to to collect data from feedback tables.

I have tables like

`tbl_parent_child_details`

```
fld_parent_id   fld_parent_name  fld_child_name   fld_class   fld_section
1               Tom              Ray               8          A
2               Dev              angelina         12          B
```

`tbl_feedback_children`

```
fld_parent_id  fld_quetion_id   fld_ans 
1              1                1
1              2                3
1              3                2
2              1                4
2              2                5
2              3                2
```

`tbl_feedback_admini`

```
fld_parent_id  fld_quetion_id   fld_ans 
1              1                1
1              2                3
1              3                2
2              1                4
2              2                5
2              3                2
```

Now my requirement is I want data of every parent in one row like:

```
Parent child q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6
tom ray 1 3 2 1 3 2
dev angelina 4 5 2 4 5 2
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should do this on presentation layer with high level languages. SQL will not format your data. It just provides data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851781/transpose-a-row-into-columns-with-mysql-without-using-unions

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation is a known as a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have a pivot function so you can replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

Your query will be similar to this:

```
select pc.fld_parent_name,
  pc.fld_child_name,
  max(case when a.fld_quetion_id = 1 then a.fld_ans end) q1,
  max(case when a.fld_quetion_id = 2 then a.fld_ans end) q2,
  max(case when a.fld_quetion_id = 3 then a.fld_ans end) q3
from tbl_parent_child_details pc
left join tbl_feedback_admini a
  on pc.fld_parent_id = a.fld_parent_id
left join tbl_feedback_children c
  on pc.fld_parent_id = c.fld_parent_id
  and a.fld_quetion_id = c.fld_quetion_id
group by pc.fld_parent_name, pc.fld_child_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4b50/6).

The above works well if you have a known number of questions to convert. If you have unknown number then you can use a prepared statement similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when a.fld_quetion_id = ''',
      fld_quetion_id,
      ''' then a.fld_ans end) AS q',
      fld_quetion_id
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_feedback_admini;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pc.fld_parent_name, 
                    pc.fld_child_name, ', @sql, ' 
                  from tbl_parent_child_details pc
                  left join tbl_feedback_admini a
                    on pc.fld_parent_id = a.fld_parent_id
                  left join tbl_feedback_children c
                    on pc.fld_parent_id = c.fld_parent_id
                    and a.fld_quetion_id = c.fld_quetion_id
                  group by pc.fld_parent_name, pc.fld_child_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4b50/10)

Both will return the result:

```
| FLD_PARENT_NAME | FLD_CHILD_NAME | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
---------------------------------------------------
|             Dev |       angelina |  4 |  5 |  2 |
|             Tom |            Ray |  1 |  3 |  2 |
```